# Android Studio KeyChain example

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, keychain

I am trying to understand KeyChain for android studio in Kotlin, but I do not see any updated examples for it. I would really appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

you can find a bit old but working example here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/KeyChainDemo?autodive=0/

If you want to run the full demo project to test the certificate imported in the KeyChain you need just to update the logic in SecureWebServerService to create a notification according to the new guidelines.

Hope this help :)